# Failed To Compile GeoJson File in Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack

i'm new with `vue js`, i want to make a `gis app`, i use `webpack+vue` and a  geojson file as the basemap. Unfortunately when i try to compile it, i got the error message : 
`Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`
this is my code :

```
export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        zona: require('@/assets/data/zona.geojson'),
        zonaLayer: null,
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      const mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]
      const options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude, mapCentre.longitude),
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
      this.zonaLayer = new google.maps.Data({map: this.map})
      this.zonaLayer.loadGeoJson(this.zona);
    }   };
```

Could anyone to help me ?

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI? You basically need to inform Webpack how to handle the `.geojson` file, preferably with the file-loader

Comment: If possible, I suspect renaming your file to end in `.json` will work _"out-of-the-box"_

Comment: @Phil hhmm, got this `Error parsing [object Object]: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` when i renaming file with `.json`

Comment: @Phil can you give me example how to inform webpack to handle `.geojson` file ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at https://github.com/soal/vue-mapbox/issues/104:

```
// webpack.conf.js
...
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'vue-mapbox': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/vue-mapbox/dist/vue-mapbox.umd.min.js'),
    }
  },
...
```

I'm still working through their quick start, but this worked for me.